# Bootstrap aumentar input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Estou fazendo uma aplicação para dispositivos móveis e estou testando a criação com Bootstrap, só que surgiu um problema:

```
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Código Estabelecimento" required  autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Senha" required>
```

No código acima usei o `input-lg` para aumentar meu input, mas ainda sim ficou pequeno quando transformado para mobile preciso deixar realmente grande(estou falando do height/altura do campo), o que devo fazer, pois sou novo no Bootstrap, desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você fala o de password que fica pequeno ?

Comment: todos os campos input.

Comment: Então, é estranho, pois essa classe input-lg, já resolveria seu problema.. O bootstrap ta funcionando direitinho em outros componentes ?

Comment: Sim.Está funcionando no ripple ele mostra o campo bem grande, mas quando gero a aplicação no phonegap. Parece não aumentar. Estou fazendo teste aqui para ver sem o input-lg e com ele adicionado, para ter certeza.

Comment: Isso, faça o teste com e sem a classe input-lg. Se nada acontecer, acho melhor ir pelo css direto mesmo, usando o seu próprio !

Comment: Não, eu testei com input-lg e ainda sim ficou pequeno e sem ele também, preciso de uma solução pelo próprio bootstrap.

Comment: Cara, então tenta pelo sistema de grid do bootstrap, aumentando o tamanho da grid, tipo col-lg-6 digamos, pode ser que funcione !

Comment: @Rogers Corrêa - pode mandar uma screenshot?

Comment: Eu só preciso aumentar, além do tamanho que está definido o input-lg!

Comment: Acho que isto tem algo errado... posta todo o código do teu form, provável que tenha um outro mixin desativando o input-lg, você está utilizando media-queries?
Declarou alguma classe do tipo `.form-group`?

Comment: faça uma regra geral e coloque padding ou height fixo em todos os imputs algo semelhante a isso `input { padding:15px; height:60px; }`

Comment: Vou esperar o Rogers responder o restante para postar uma resposta, ainda acho que ele tá fazendo mixin sem querer.

Answer (score 1):

utilize as classes de grid, se vc usa bootstrap 3 experimente colocar no campo

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control col-lg-6" placeholder="email@email.com" />
```

nesse caso o campo teria a metade de um grid em grandes dispositivos!

alterando o valor é claro que aumenta ou diminui, bem como utilizar col-sm-* etc. para controlar a responsividade